# How to import/expand noweb refs in evaluated (exported) source blocks in org-babel?

Tags: emacs, org-mode, literate-programming, org-babel, reproducible-research

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
* Define some functions
#+begin_src python :noweb_ref defs
   def f1(a,b,c):
     return True
   def f2(d,e,f):
     return False
#+end_src

* Use them in a results-exported block later
#+begin_src python :results output :exports both :tangle yes
<<defs>>
print "test results:"
print f1(1,2,3)
#end_src
```

What I want to happen is for <<defs>> to be expanded tangle-style when the block is evaluated to produce the export output.  What actually happens is that <<defs>> gets evaluated literally and causes a syntax error.

When tangling blocks like this to an output file, everything works perfectly, but I can't figure out how to do the same thing when I'm *exporting* the buffer.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure to really understand your point... but

1) you miss a `noweb:yes` header argument

2) you can use `<<func()>>` to insert the **results** of evaluating func (instead of the **code** of func) -- that's here that I'm not sure about what you really want.

Comment: The `:noweb yes` header was exactly my problem.  I'd tried `:noweb tangle` and `:tangle yes`.  Now that you point it out, the documentation at http://orgmode.org/manual/noweb.html#noweb is perfectly clear.

Comment: Excellent!  BTW, on the 2nd point, dunno why this is badly written, but you should read <<func()>>, that is your function followed by open and closing parens, all between doubled angular brackets

Comment: S.O. tried to turn into HTML, I believe.  I edited your answer so it would show up, but the edit is waiting in some sort of review queue, I think,

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `:noweb no-export`. That shows the noweb-syntax in exported files but expands the code blocks when evaluating or tangling the files.

`:noweb strip-export` is great if you just want to show an algorithm:

```python
<<prep>>
result = A + B
<<plot>>
```

The exported file then shows this:

```python
result = A + B
```